# Permission issue with the shared folder - Oracle Virtualbox - Ubuntu guest VM

Tags: virtualbox, oracle, shared-folders

**Setup:** I have installed Oracle Virtualbox 6.1.40 on my Windows 11 host. Running an Ubuntu 22.04 VM.

I have logged in as a non-root (user name: bhuvan). I have successfully configured a shared folder in the VM as shown below. When I click on the shared folder in the FileManager, I am getting a PermissionError. However, I could access it from the root user. How to resolve the permission issue?

I see the shared folder is created with root:vboxsf ownership.

Update 30/Dec/22: Upgraded the Ubuntu to 22.04. The problem still persists.

[image: Shared Folder Configuration]

[image: PermissionError]

Comment: Thanks @guiverc. I will upgrade Ubuntu VM. One correction, I am using Windows 11 host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to add your non-root user to the vboxsf group.

```
sudo adduser {username} vboxsf
```

OR

```
sudo usermod -a -G vboxsf {user}
```

Either of those should work for you.

Comment: Thanks @R34p3r. After running "sudo adduser {username} vboxsf", I restarted my VM. Then the issue is resolved.

Comment: Thanks!  The second one must be used on centos. It lacks adduser at least in this form. Don't forget to reboot the VM.